# Counting files with metadata in a GridFS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, gridfs

I've been trying to implement a feature into a website that displays the number of unread files in a GridFS. Each file, when stored, is defined with the metadata `completed: "false"`. In the following helper function, I try to find the number of files that are still labeled with this data.

```
incomplete_diagnostics_count: function() {
return Diagnostics.find({metadata: {completed: "false"}}).count();
},
```

As of now, this code doesn't work. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't a distinct answer anywhere on the internet, but apparently it was just a syntax error:

`incomplete_diagnostics_count: function() {
  return Diagnostics.find({},{metadata: {completed: "false"}}).count();
},`

The extra bracket in the `find()` dependents fixed it.